# how to add mysql jdbc connector in classpath

Tags: solr, classpath

I have upgraded to solr 3.6 to SOLR 4.0. i am using dataimporthandler to extract data from database. 
I have copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar into apache-solr-4.0.0-ALPHA/example/lib folder.

I have also added it in classpath using cmd

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip:/usr/solr4/apache-solr-4.0.0-ALPHA/example/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
```

When i browse solr/admin page and click on java properties it shows all .jar files from solr-home/lib folder in java.class.path but doesnt add mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar

What will be the reason that mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar not getting added in java classpath?

let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: Why not put that jar within the solr-home/lib too among other jars you're using? Those jars are loaded from a different class loader within Solr itself.

Comment: i have put mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar at solr-home/lib folder where other .jar files stored.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get if you solved then or not. Hope so!